# Custom data validation formula: If adjacent cell is 0 return N/A else allow number entry

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm not sure if this is even possible with the, what that the custom formulas work for data validation in excel, but this is what I would like to do:

I want to set a data validation criterion to all cells in column B whereby: If value in adjacent cell A is 0 value in cell B must be N/A, otherwise allow a decimal (0-100) to be entered to be entered.

For example, here:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 0 |  |
| **2** | 1 |  |

I want B1 to automatically be N/A with no other value allowed, and B2 to allow any decimal number between 0-100.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can't do that with formulas. To change B1 value to N/A on some condition, formula must be in B1. If there is formula in B1, you would need to overwrite it with user input 1-100

Comment: Data validation won't automatically enter na() or any value, but will control the number entered between 0-100.

Comment: So what you are saying is it is not possible to do this. Only to control number entry in B or have a formula in B?

Comment: So use an if() in cell B1: if(A1=0,na(),""). Then you can manually overwrite the cell with any number as you wish, controlling the value entered with data validation.

Comment: @CharlieVagg actually you can do this using two helper columns. If i am not mistaken, also do you need decimal numbers from 1-100 or just the whole numbers? Can you confirm by looking at this `.Gif` and let me know **[here](https://imgur.com/gallery/qSVKRyK)**